# Turning Google Earth plugin animation into a video

Tags: video-capture, google-earth-plugin

I've created an animation which runs inside of the Google Earth plugin (browser) and I'd like to somehow encode this animation into a video format that I can upload to YouTube or a related video site. Are there any tools out there to help me do this?

**EDIT: more detail
This animation changes depending on user input. So it needs to be scalable. The user would click a button: download video after which a server would convert the animation.

Comment: This is strictly prohibited by the Terms of Service. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

Comment: Even if you have a Google Earth Pro license? Seems to be part of the advertised package? http://earth.google.com/support/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=22379&topic=23666

Comment: Yes, even if you have a pro licence as that is talking about the "Google Earth application" not the "Javascript Api". The Api has no "Pro" licence and no Movie Maker feature...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) to record a video of the animation running on your machine.